# Array pagination creates empty extra page

Tags: php, arrays, pagination

I have an array of files in a directory. I want to limit them to a certain number per page. I set it to 5 for testing purposes. It creates an extra page with no output on it. I can't figure out why it's creating the extra page. Anyone have any ideas?

```
<?php
$offset = '5';
$dir    = 'posts';
$files1 = array_diff(scandir($dir), array(
    '..',
    '.'
));



if (isset($_GET['bpage'])) {
    $bpage = $_GET['bpage'];
} else {
    $bpage = 1;
}

$count = count($files1);

if ($bpage < 1) {
    $bpage = 1;
}

$pagearray = array_chunk($files1, $offset);

$pagearray = $pagearray[$bpage];


foreach ($pagearray as $item) {
    echo $item . '<br />';
}

$startResults = ($bpage - 1) * $offset;
$totalPages   = ceil($count / $offset);

echo '<div class="pagination pagination-centered"><ul>';
echo '<li><a href="?bpage=1">First</a></li>';

for ($i = 1; $i <= $totalPages; $i++) {
    if ($i == $bpage)
        echo '<li class="active"><a href="#">' . $i . '</a></li>';
    else
        echo '<li><a href="?bpage=' . $i . '">' . $i . '</a></li>';
}

echo '<li><a href="?bpage=' . $totalPages . '">Last</a></li>';
echo '</ul></div>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change line:

```
$pagearray = $pagearray[$bpage];
```

into:

```
$pagearray = $pagearray[$bpage-1];
```

because in PHP indexes in array are from 0 not 1.

In your code for page 1 you displayed data at index 1 and that was in fact 2nd element of array. That's way at last page you didn't have any elements because there was no data at index `$totalPages` (last one was at `$totalPages-1`)

Comment: I feel pretty dumb.. I was fighting with that for an hour and forgot 2 characters.. It happens.